# Splash screen for nuxt.js pwa (add to home screen ios and Apk pwa)

Tags: ios, vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps, splash-screen

Hey im trying to set splash screen for my nuxt js project and ive already try All meta tags like these :
———-

```
{link rel:"apple-touch-startup- image",media:"screen and (device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)",href:"splash/launch-2688x1242.png"}
```

———-

In every sizes in my nuxt-config.js but not working ,
Please help me out if u know how can i set a splash screen for my nuxt project

Comment: Not sure about what you are trying to do here. What do you call a splash screen here? If you have it as a PWA (android), the loading may be super quick. If you're loading it in the web, there is a loader while the SPA info got fetched. On iOS, there is no PWA so far to my knowledge. Also, give a read to this one: https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/icon

Comment: hey ! im looking for somthing like this https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/all-splash-screen_inspiration.png                                            
(thats what we call splash screen i guess)

Answer (score 1):

For this, you could customize the loading indicator: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/loading/#the-loading-indicator-property
And use a custom one, where you do design your *splash screen*.

Not sure if the fact that it's a PWA will require additional work but if it does, this one should fix it: https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/icon/